# Why are my text forms slightly misaligned?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a login modal for my website -

code pen link @ https://codepen.io/carlyraejepsenstan/pen/vYGNVJp

**This is a screenshot:**

[image: slanted forms]

I tried adding `float:left` to the input styles.  It works, but the modal background gets compressed into a tiny line:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: If you use float, you need to set `overflow: hidden;` to the container.

Comment: But a simple `text-align: left` to the container would suffice (without float)

Comment: Dont use floating in 2020. Flex is your friend: `display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;` add these properties to `<form>` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can add clearfix.**

Add the `clearfix` class inside the HTML like this:

```html
<div id="modal-container" class="clearfix">
```

And define `clearfix` in your CSS like this:

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

[View at codepen](https://codepen.io/ppwater/pen/xxVZEYo)

Comment: Thanks!  What does `content: ""` do?

Comment: if you are going to write ::after then you have to write content:"something" but since we don't need it, I just writed no contents.    I don't know it realy well so look at this link too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<form style="float:left;>`
or
You can add a p tag `<p align="left"></p>`